# 400 bad request when connecting to sp2007 kerberos

Tags: 2007, kerberos, https, http-400-bad-request

I am trying to connect from a java client to sharepoint.
I manageds to connect to 
sp2010 ntlm
sp2010 kerberos
sp2007 ntlm
but sp2007 kerberos throws the error below(maybe from the iis):

what could be the problem?  how can I check whats wrong ? (the connection is https)

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977655/http-400-request-header-too-long-error-when-accessing-asp-net-application) and changed MaxFieldLength and the MaxRequestBytes registry settings but it didnt help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: can you add code for the request your making please as thats where things are getting wrong

Comment: What kind of request is it. Please show a dump from Fiddler or similar.

Comment: the SharePoint is https, so i cant inspect  with fiddler.

Comment: Fiddler can decrypt HTTPS traffic. See here: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-traffic-recording

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool - httpclientAuthHelper
for easly accessing NTLM and kerberos from JAVA, no configuratino required.

it worked great for this.
https://github.com/DovAmir/httpclientAuthHelper